# extjs: getting reference to record changed in cell edit

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with cell selection and cell editing setup.

If I edit a cell, how can I grab a reference to the underlying record that changed? I have tried:

- listening on grid's store's `datachanged`
- listening on grid's store's `update`
- listening on editor's `complete`

Comment: Looks like a found it. Need to listen on grid's `edit`, which is undocumented and only shows up when you have a editor plugin attached..

Comment: It depends, where exactly do you want that reference? Inside your edit listener? Inside the form field your editing, you question doesn't specify what you trying to do... it's hard to point you to the right direction...